# NDB model's custom property not returning correct value when deployed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have declared 2 ndb models as follows:

```
class Event(ndb.Model):
    event_type = ndb.KeyProperty()

    @property
    def installments(self):
        return EventInstallment.query().filter(EventInstallment.event == self.key).count()

class EventInstallment(ndb.Model):
    event = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

I persist a single entity of type Event and another of type EventInstallment. EventInstallment.event is the Key of the declared Event entity. The following query works (i.e. returns 1) when run locally but not when deployed:

```
event_query = Event.query()
event_query = event_query.filter(ndb.GenericProperty('installments') > 0)
print event_query.count()
```

I have cleared memcache, and double checked that all properties of EventInstallment are correct. When opening the EventInstallment entity in datastoreviewer it has a hotlink to the Event key, as expected.

Can someone tell me what's going wrong here? Specifically I'm curious to know why this works locally and not when deployed.

Comment: How much time between when you `.put()` the `EventInstallment` entity and when your 2nd code snippet runs?

Comment: Well - in testing it was anywhere up to about 30 minutes - I don't think it was a timing issue.

Comment: Also notice that... if you just want to count the query results fetch only keys (.count(keys_only=True)

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` must be able to run in the datastore, and, in a deployed app, `filter(ndb.GenericProperty('installments') > 0)` clearly can't (the simulation `dev_appserver` does is not 100% accurate, I bet its authors never dreamed of checking for something like that).

Rather, what you want is a `ComputedProperty`, which is computed and actually sent to the datastore at `put` time, allowing the datastore to perform searches on it. To wit:

```
class Event(ndb.Model):
    event_type = ndb.KeyProperty()

    @property
    def _installments(self):
        return EventInstallment.query().filter(EventInstallment.event == self.key).count()

    installments = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self._installments)
```

Now, `filter(Event.installments > 0)` will work -- as long as the number of related `EventInstallment` entities *at the time the `Event` entity was last `put`* was positive. (The datastore won't re-run any code to update `Event` entities when `EventInstallment` entities are added, removed, or altered; `ComputedProperty` is computed at `put` time on the entity it belongs to, and it's computed on the appengine instance side of things, i.e in "application level code", just before the entity's sent to the datastore side of things).

You may want to work the other way 'round: query for `EventInstallment` entities, making a set of their `event` properties to remove duplicates, and using the `len` of that set as your desired count. Yes, that requires fetching all of them, but counting is not much faster than fetching anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Yes - the reason I'm using a custom property is because more instalments get added over time - so I wanted a simple way to query the number of instalments per event. This is the reason I never used ComputedProperty - as the number should change over time.

Comment: As for fetch vs count, I was under the impression that fetch is quite expensive, whereas count is a lot lot cheaper in terms of reads?

Comment: @user714852, the number will **not** automagically "change over time" *in the datastore*, where it matters for queries, with either kind of property (the kind you've used doesn't get sent to the datastore **at all**). `count` is only modestly cheaper than `fetch` (with a projection query getting just one field, or if feasible keys only, if the entities are large; the entity you show is very small, so, no big deal). Alternatively, you can denormalize the model, keep a counter on the event and increment it (transactionally, to be sure) when installments are added. But, transaction=slower.